# How to create a shader that can display a texture made out of many small images in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader, shaderlab

So what I'm trying to do is load satellite images from an SQL table and wrap them around a sphere to create a globe. I know I've got loading the images covered, I'm just not sure how to make my shader display the images in the correct orientation.

I've gone to the Unity Forums as well as checked out [this code](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-TextureArrays.html?_ga=2.76391829.1408735510.1568984793-2059966846.1560883833) from the Unity Docs.

Using the linked shader code and the help I received on the forums, here's the code I've ended up with:

```cs
Properties
    {
        _MainTexArray("Tex", 2DArray) = "" {}
        _SliceRange("Slices", Range(0,32)) = 6
        _UVScale("UVScale", Float) = 1
        _COLUMNS("Columns", Range(0, 5)) = 1
        _ROWS("Rows", Range(0, 5)) = 1
        _CELLS("Cells", Range(0, 32)) = 16
    }
        SubShader
        {
            Pass
            {
                CGPROGRAM
                #pragma vertex vert
                #pragma fragment frag
                // texture arrays are not available everywhere,
                // only compile shader on platforms where they are
                #pragma require 2darray

                #include "UnityCG.cginc"

                struct v2f
                {
                    float3 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                    float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
                };

                float _SliceRange;
                float _UVScale;

                v2f vert(float4 vertex : POSITION)
                {
                    v2f o;
                    o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(vertex);
                    o.uv.xy = (vertex.xy + 0.5) * _UVScale;
                    o.uv.z = (vertex.z + 0.5) * _SliceRange;
                    return o;
                }
                float _COLUMNS; //Columns and rows only go between 0 and 1
                float _ROWS;
                float _CELLS;
                UNITY_DECLARE_TEX2DARRAY(_MainTexArray);        
                half4 frag(v2f i) : SV_Target
                {
                    float3 uv = float3(i.uv.x * _CELLS, i.uv.y * _CELLS, 0);
                    uv.z = floor(i.uv.x / _COLUMNS) * floor(i.uv.y / _ROWS);
                    return UNITY_SAMPLE_TEX2DARRAY(_MainTexArray, uv / _CELLS); 
                }
                ENDCG
            }
        }
```

Using that I've gotten my materials to look like this: 
[image: distorted texture on plane and sphere]

Here's the code that I'm using to load the SQL images:

```cs
textures = new Texture2D[size];
            for (int x = 0; x <= 7; x++) 
            {
                for (int y = 0; y <= 3; y++)
                {
                    textures[count] = tiler.Read(x, y, 2); //The z determines the zoom level, so I wouldn't want them all loaded at once
                    if (textures[count] != null) TextureScale.Bilinear(textures[count], 256, 256);
                    count++;
                }
            }


        texArr = new Texture2DArray(256, 256, textures.Length, TextureFormat.RGBA32, true, true);
        texArr.filterMode = FilterMode.Bilinear;
        texArr.wrapMode = TextureWrapMode.Repeat;
        for (int i = 0; i < textures.Length; i++)
        {
            if (textures[i] == null) continue;
            texArr.SetPixels(textures[i].GetPixels(0), i, 0);
        }    
        texArr.Apply();
        mat.SetTexture("_MainTexArray", texArr);
```

In the SQL Table, the x and y determines the position of the tile and the z determines the zoom level. I'm just working with one zoom level for now.

Sorry for linking the whole shader class, but I'm not very experienced with shaders so I don't quite know where the problem lies.

Comment: [This similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70205085/1092820) may be of interest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can index into the array of photos such that you effectively have an equirectangular projection of the globe, you could try using a modified form of the shader code by [Farfarer from the Unity forums](https://forum.unity.com/threads/what-is-wrong-with-unitys-spherical-mapping-how-to-fix-it.321205/#post-2083408) copied and modified slightly below:

```
Shader "Custom/Equirectangular" {
    Properties{
        _MainTexArray("Tex", 2DArray) = "" {}
        _COLUMNS("Columns", Int) = 2
        _ROWS("Rows", Int) = 2
    }

        SubShader{
            Pass {
                Tags {"LightMode" = "Always"}

                CGPROGRAM
                    #pragma vertex vert
                    #pragma fragment frag
                    #pragma require 2darray

                    #include "UnityCG.cginc"

                    struct appdata {
                       float4 vertex : POSITION;
                       float3 normal : NORMAL;
                    };

                    struct v2f
                    {
                        float4    pos : SV_POSITION;
                        float3    normal : TEXCOORD0;
                    };

                    v2f vert(appdata v)
                    {
                        v2f o;
                        o.pos = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                        o.normal = v.normal;
                        return o;
                    }

                    UNITY_DECLARE_TEX2DARRAY(_MainTexArray);

                    int _ROWS;
                    int _COLUMNS;

                    #define PI 3.141592653589793

                    inline float2 RadialCoords(float3 a_coords)
                    {
                        float3 a_coords_n = normalize(a_coords);
                        float lon = atan2(a_coords_n.z, a_coords_n.x);
                        float lat = acos(a_coords_n.y);
                        float2 sphereCoords = float2(lon, lat) * (1.0 / PI);
                        return float2(sphereCoords.x * 0.5 + 0.5, 1 - sphereCoords.y);
                    }

                    float4 frag(v2f IN) : COLOR
                    {
                        float2 equiUV = RadialCoords(IN.normal);

                        float2 texIndex;
                        float2 uvInTex = modf(equiUV * float2(_COLUMNS,_ROWS), texIndex);

                        int flatTexIndex = texIndex.x * _ROWS + texIndex.y;

                        return UNITY_SAMPLE_TEX2DARRAY(_MainTexArray,
                                float3(uvInTex, flatTexIndex));
                    }
                ENDCG
            }
        }
    FallBack "VertexLit"
}
```

You also need to use

```
texArr = new Texture2DArray(256, 256, textures.Length, TextureFormat.RGBA32, false, true);
```

instead of

```
texArr = new Texture2DArray(256, 256, textures.Length, TextureFormat.RGBA32, true, false);
```

It works for me if I attach this script to a sphere:

```
Material myMat;
public List<Texture2D> texes;

IEnumerator Start()
{
    yield return null;
    myMat = GetComponent<Renderer>().material;

    Texture2DArray texArr = new Texture2DArray(256, 256, 9, 
            TextureFormat.RGBA32, false, true);
    texArr.filterMode = FilterMode.Bilinear;
    texArr.wrapMode = TextureWrapMode.Clamp;

    for (int i = 0 ; i < texes.Count ; i++)
    {
        texArr.SetPixels(texes[i].GetPixels(), i, 0);
    }

    texArr.Apply();

    myMat.SetTexture("_MainTexArray", texArr);
}
```

and in `texes` I add these textures in order:

0: [image: bottom left at index 0]

1: [image: center left at index 1]

2: [image: top left at index 2]

3: [image: bottom center at index 3]

4: [image: center at index 4]

5: [image: top center at index 5]

6: [image: bottom right at index 6]

7: [image: center right at index 7]

8: [image: top right at index 8]

and set 3 for Rows and Columns, it produces decent results:

[image: seamless wrapped texture array]

If bilinear filtering is enabled, there are still some artifacts at the borders of the textures. But these artifacts have to be zoomed in quite close to see. Due to the lack of adjacent pixels for bilinear filtering they mostly appear as improperly blended or missing pixels:

[image]

Of course this example doesn't properly tile so there is an obvious seam along one longitude line:

[image: only seam where texture doesn't repeat]

Since this setup expects normals from a sphere, this only works on things with normals that approximate those of a sphere. So it would not render properly on a plane, for instance.

Comment: This has been a monumental improvement. Unfortunately there are still a couple minor (though unfortunately non-negligible) issues. [There are obvious grid lines separating each tile.](https://forum.unity.com/attachments/screenshot-14-png.486164/?temp_hash=5ac7f5791b4f7b18fc2b2d8d48395661).
[There's some distortion at the top.](https://forum.unity.com/attachments/screenshot-15-png.486167/?temp_hash=5ac7f5791b4f7b18fc2b2d8d48395661).
Some of these issues may be because of the images themselves. The SQL Table I've been given doesn't allow me to look at the static images so I'm not sure.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199747/discussion-between-ruzihm-and-mike-od).

Comment: This final answer solved the problem. My issue was doing 
texArr = new Texture2DArray(256, 256, textures.Length, TextureFormat.RGBA32, true, false);
instead of
texArr = new Texture2DArray(256, 256, textures.Length, TextureFormat.RGBA32, false, true);
The grid lines are gone. Thanks so much for sticking with me on this problem, Ruzihm.